# RestKit creating multiple to many relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to parse a json response for use with a core data model. This is a sample from the json :

```
  {
      "@context": "TVSchedule",
      "ReturnCode": "0",
      "ReturnMessage": "Successful request",
      "Channel": [
        {
          "ChannelId": "http%…..0",
          "Program": [
            {
              "@programId": "http……..",
              "Title": "Divorce Court",
              "ProgramLogo": "http://00_180x101.png",
              "ProgramLogos": [
                {
                  "@size": "small",
                  "#text": "http://.png"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "large",
                  "#text": "191.png"
                }
              ],
              "ProgramDetailsURL": "http:9",
              "PublishedStartTime": "2013-07-01T19:00:00",
              "PublishedEndTime": "2013-07-01T19:30:00",
              "Duration": "00:00:30:00",
              "RatingInfo": {
                "@system": "MPAA",
                "@code": "TV-PG",
                "@age": "10",
                "Title": "Not recommended for children under 10 years",
                "Logo": "http://"
              },
              "ShortDescription": "She says she cannot trust him .",
              "Year": "2013",
              "Genres": [
                "Series",
                "Reality",
                "Public Affairs",
                "News",
                "Episodic"
              ]
            },
```

I need to get this in CoreData where I have an entity named Channel that will hold the channelId an a one-to-many relationship with an entity named program that will keep a list of the attributes on that level and will have to-many relationships with entities ProgramLogo (from the "ProgramLogos" in the json file) Genres (the genres string array will be added as a number of Genre entities that contain only one string attribute),RatingsInfo entity (one to one relationship from the corresponding dictionary), the RatingsInfo does not appear on all Programs ...

Here is the RestKit code I use:

```
 RKEntityMapping *channelMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kCDChannelEntity inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    channelMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ kCDChannelId ];

    [channelMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                       kJsonChannelId : kCDChannelId
     }];



    RKEntityMapping *programMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kCDProgramEntity inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];


    [programMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                       @"@programId" : kCDProgramId ,
                                     @"ProgramLogo" : kCDProgramLogo,
                              @"ProgramDetailsURL" : kCDProgramDetailsUrl,
                                       @"Duration"  : kCDProgramDuration,
                              @"PublishedStartTime" : kCDProgramStartTime,
                                @"PublishedEndTime" : kCDProgramEndTime,
                                           @"Title" : kCDProgramTitle,
                                            @"Year" : kCDProgramYear,
                                @"ShortDescription" : kCDProgramShortDescription
     }];

    [RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatterForString:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'" inTimeZone:nil];

    [channelMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Program" toKeyPath:kCDChannelHasProgramsRel withMapping:programMapping]];// ??


    RKEntityMapping *parentalRatingMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kCDParentalRatingEntity inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [parentalRatingMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                           @"Program.RatingsInfo.@age": kCDParentalRatingAge,
                                         @"Program.RatingsInfo.@code" : kCDParentalRatingCode,
                                         @"Program.RatingsInfo.Logo" : kCDParentalRatingLogo,
                                       @"Program.RatingsInfo.@system" : kCDParentalRatingSystem,
                                        @"Program.RatingsInfo.Title" : kCDParentalRatingTitle}];

    [programMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Program.RatingsInfo" toKeyPath:kCDProgramHasParentalRatingRel withMapping:parentalRatingMapping]];// ??



    RKEntityMapping *genresMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kCDGenreEntity inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [genresMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"Program.Genres": kCDGenreName
     }];

    [programMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Program.Genres" toKeyPath:kCDProgramHasGenres withMapping:genresMapping]];


    RKEntityMapping *logoMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kCDProgramLogoEntity inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [logoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"Program.ProgramLogos.@size" : kCDLogoSize,
     @"Program.ProgramLogos.#text" : kCDLogoText
     }];
```

Ok, now there are two problems :
1) How to parse the two non-KVO arrays (Genres, each string in a different entity, and ProgramLogos (each dict in a entity)

2) RestKit doesn't parse the programId (key "@programId") why? Does the "@" in the key stops the parsing?

I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFDictionary 0x958f980> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key programId.'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `channelResponseDescriptor` should have a keyPath of @"Channel". Hard to tell if anything else is wrong due to all the constants. It seems that just the top level descriptor needs more info on where it should be applied.

---

Generally, you create all of your mappings to be related to each other. Based on the structure of your JSON there is a good chance you don't need so many response descriptors, just the top level one for channels, then all of the mappings are used to navigate down through the structure using the relationships.

---

For example, you have JSON:

```
  "Channel": [
    {
      "ChannelId": "http%…..0",
      "Program": [
        {...
```

You could have a relationship between the channel and program entities and a corresponding relationship between the mappings so that when the channel is mapped it will navigate to the program section of the JSON, map the programs and then connect the objects. You appear to have this:

```
[channelMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:kJsonProgram toKeyPath:kCDChannelHasProgramsRel withMapping:programMapping]];
```

(which has a typo in your code as it should be applied to the `channelMapping`, not the `programMapping`)

So the `programResponseDescriptor` probably isn't required and could just cause your mapping results to contain duplicate items.

Comment: That's what I think too... I'm not sure about the keyPaths... how are they created for the embedded objects and relationships

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: Doesn't any entity need it's own response descriptor?

Comment: You need at least one response descriptor for the channel.

Comment: I removed the other response descriptors and now the channels get processed but not anything else...

Comment: Noticed the typo in your relationship mappings now, see my last edit.

Comment: so all the relationship mappings should be added to the channelMapping? Even the ones that have a relationship with the program entity?

Comment: No, they should be added to the appropriate mapping based on what they are contained in. So the rating relationship should be added to the program mapping.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32751/discussion-between-user426132-and-wain)